# Object Orientated Programming Practice - Concepts/Entities into Objects

Tags: python, oop

I'm very amateur when it comes to OOP, self taught using python.

My main concern is that of breaking concepts or entities into objects.

For instance, I have just written some code that controls a traffic light system attached to my raspberry pi.

The system contains:

- A car set off traffic lights (red, yellow, green).
- A button to request a crossing.
- And a green and red light to tell pedestrians when to cross

Now i ended up modelling my code as one entire class. Where methods inside the object call other methods in the object. E.g. when the object is initialized, the initialize method calls a "wait for button press" method, when the button press is detected that method then calls a "run through light sequence" method.

Is this bad practice? Should each concept/entity be a separate class/object, e.g. traffic light object, button object, pedestrian light object?

Sorry for the openness of the question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should post this answer, with the code, in codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Generally, I'd say break down to different objects.

Comment: Try to at least differentiate between methods that are for interaction with other entities(objects) and methods that are used for initialization or setup.
Think a bit about interfaces and try to break your stuff down in a natural manner. But nevertheless try not to overengineer simple problems and slowly evolve towards object-oriented practices imho.

Comment: Having one huge class is just writing procedural code under an OO facade. So, you should break down the problem into smaller entities.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. How far should one go when breaking down entities into objects? E.g. taking my example, would an object for each LED be going too far?

Comment: Depends on the complexity of your LEDs, but generally speaking, yes make a meaningful interface to your LEDs and let your traffic light aggregate them. This will considerably change the way you work with your entities and force you to create clean interfaces and decouples your entitites behaviour from implementation details. Any class just needs to know what the LED can do, but not how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Basically you class is doing too much.

What you can do is something like the following:

Have separate classes for car trafficlights, pedestrian traffic lights and the button to request to start crossing.

After that you can inject the button class into the pedestrian light class. And inject both the car as well as the pedestrian class into the "control" / "manage" class where the classes are used to manage the lights.

You could even abstract it even further after this by for example injecting the actual lights into the trafficlights classes.

You may also want to read about the other [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, those SOLID principles look really interesting. Although no idea yet what injecting is or how it works.

Comment: @Cornucopia see this: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/ :)

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated. The links and yourself have taught me much.